# Allow a field to be empty using bindParam()

Tags: php, pdo

I have a search/filter form with pagination, so I had to the $_GET to get the parameters in the url. Now I wanted to use also prepared statement to be safer.

The problem is that if I leave an empty field I get an error. Is there a way to bypass this issue?
I searched this wbsite, and I found seminar problem, but they all about inserting empty fields into database.

```
$input = $_GET['input'];

$categories = $_GET['category'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
$zipcode = $_GET['zipcode'];
$targetpage = "send.php";
$limit = 3;

//This query checks for data
  $qq = " SELECT * FROM classified where confirm='0' ";
    if (!empty($input)) {
        $qq .= "AND title LIKE :input ";
    }
    if (!empty($categories) ){
        $qq .= "AND id_cat = :categories ";
    }

    if (!empty($state) ) {
        $qq .= "AND id_state = :state ";
    }

            if (!empty($zipcode) ) {
        $qq .= "AND zipcode = :zipcode ";
    }


    $qq .= "ORDER BY date DESC ";
    $qq = $db->prepare($qq);
   $input = "%".$input."%";
    // Bind the parameter
$qq->execute(array(':input'=> $input,
 ':categories'=> $categories,
 ':state'=> $state,
 ':zipcode'=> $zipcode  ));
```

The error i am getting is

```
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined  
 in ....send.php on line 56
```

which is  ':zipcode'=> $zipcode  ));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try not to repeat yourself. Imagine if you have 50 fields in search filter.

```
  $input = $_GET['input'];
  $categories = $_GET['category'];
  $state = $_GET['state'];
  $zipcode = $_GET['zipcode'];
  $targetpage = "send.php";
  $limit = 3;
  $Param = array();
 //This query checks for data
 $qq = " SELECT * FROM classified where confirm='0' ";
 if (!empty($input)) {
    $qq .= "AND title LIKE :input ";
    $Param[':input'] = $input;
}
if (!empty($categories) ){
    $qq .= "AND id_cat = :categories ";
    $Param[':categories'] = $categories ;
}

if (!empty($state) ) {
    $qq .= "AND id_state = :state ";
    $Param[':state'] = $state ;
}

        if (!empty($zipcode) ) {
    $qq .= "AND zipcode = :zipcode ";
    $Param[':zipcode'] = $zipcode ;
}


$qq .= "ORDER BY date DESC ";
$qq = $db->prepare($qq);
$qq->execute($Param);
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

Just build the array to bind when building the query

```
    $to_bind = array();
    if (!empty($input)) {
        $qq .= "AND title LIKE :input ";
        $to_bind[':input'] = $input;
    }
    if (!empty($categories) ){
        $qq .= "AND id_cat = :categories ";
        $to_bind[':categories'] = $categories ;
    }

    if (!empty($state) ) {
        $qq .= "AND id_state = :state ";
        $to_bind[':state'] = $state ;
    }

   if (!empty($zipcode) ) {
        $qq .= "AND zipcode = :zipcode ";
        $to_bind[':zipcode'] = $zipcode ;
   }
   ...
   $qq->execute($to_bind);
```

I'm not sure if passing an empty array will cause a problem incase all the parameters are empty.

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine even with all fields empty. The  same thing with @CheJug code, thanks

Comment: Kind of a vague question, is there a "nicer" or more "programmatic" way to do that? I feel sloppy when I have to manually type out all the parameters (lots of duplicates).